# How to know type of image

Tags: image, matlab

When I use `imread` in MATLAB and read an image, how would I know if it is RGB, gray scale or single programmatically?

```
    I1 = imread('sample_image.jpg');
```

How can I know what type `I1` is before any conversion?

Comment: you should read this: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/03/09/what-happened-to-isgray-isind-isbw-and-isrgb/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `imfinfo` to retrieve information about an image file before you load it:

```
info = imfinfo('sample_image.jpg');
info.ColorType % e.g. 'grayscale', 'truecolor', 'indexed'
info.BitDepth % e.g. 8, 16
```

You can also look at the help section on imread to see what the output class will be for different file types.  The problem comes in determining the difference between a grayscale image, and an indexed colour file - these will have the same size and class.  In this case you need to check `ColorType` beforehand and load the colormap in when you read the image:

`[I, map] = imread(filename)`